# Build an SPFX web part which render an HTML BOX which have a configurable Title, Description and Clickable Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I want to build an SPFX web part, which should allow me to display this Box:-

[image]

where the Box will have a configurable Title,Description text & clickable button. so the user can add this web part inside any modern page, and define the Title, Description,the button title & the button URL.. so is there any available SPFX which can allow me to have these features, if the answer is No, then it is possible to build such SPFX?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for an SPFx compatible component. There is SPFx controls library, the control you are looking for is probably called `Placeholder`.

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/Placeholder/